# Chrome and Opera delete record data when editing a record

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome

I'm new to php and mysql, I'm using a script like CMS, my problem that I can write new article, but when editing it on chrome or opera all of article content is not shown for editing and deleted and it's not the case with firefox, here below the edit php script,

```
<?php echo link_tag('assets/themes/' . $this->selected_theme . '/'.UIKIT_VERSION.'/css/' . $this->session->userdata('selected-theme')); ?>
<script src="<?php echo base_url() ?>assets/themes/<?php echo $this->selected_theme . '/ckeditor/ckeditor.js'; ?>"></script>
<h4><i class="uk-icon-edit"></i> edit step </h4>
<hr class="uk-article-divider">
<?php $this->load->view('user/template/default/flash_data') ?>
<?php
$attributes = array(
    'method' => 'post',
    'class' => 'uk-form'
);
echo form_open_multipart('articles/edit/' . $step->step_id, $attributes) ?>
<div class="uk-form-controls">
    <label class="uk-form-label">
        <?php if ($step->step_photo_url) { ?>
            <img src="<?php echo $step->step_photo_url ?>" class="uk-thumbnail-small"/><br/>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <i class="uk-icon-image uk-icon-large"></i>
        <?php } ?>

    </label><br/>
    <input type="file" name="step_photo_url"/>
    <br/>
    <label class="uk-form-label uk-text-muted uk-text-bold">Or Enter a URL</label>
    <input class="uk-width-90 uk-form-large" type="text" placeholder="Image Url" name="step_photo_url"
           value="<?php echo set_value('step_photo_url', $step->step_photo_url, true) ?>"/>
    <?php echo form_error('step_photo_url') ?>
</div>
<div class="uk-form-controls uk-margin-top">
    <div class="uk-form-controls uk-margin-bottom">
        <input value="<?php echo $step->step_title ?>" name="step_title" class="uk-width-90 uk-form-large"
               type="text" placeholder="step title">
        <?php echo form_error('step_title'); ?>
    </div>
    <div class="uk-margin-bottom uk-form-controls">
            <textarea name="step_description" rows="4" class="uk-width-90 uk-form-large ckeditor"
                      placeholder="Enter Description"><?php echo set_value('step_description', $step->step_description,
                    true) ?></textarea>
        <?php echo form_error('step_description'); ?>
    </div>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('articles/delete/' . $step->step_id) ?>"
       class="uk-button uk-button-danger uk-float-left">Delete</a>
    <button class="uk-button uk-button-success uk-float-right">Save</button>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard problem to guess at with what you have, though it sounds like a mistake I made when I first started working with PHP and databases. That is converting output in value fields using `htmlspecialchars($value,ENT_QUOTES)`. If you have this value:

```
$content = '"What are you talking about?" she asked, "that is ridiculous!"';
```

then you echo into an input field for editing:

```
<input name="test" value="<?php echo $content ?>" />
```

The html output is:

```
<input name="test" value=""What are you talking about?" she asked, "that is ridiculous!"" />
```

which has two sets of quotes, and most browsers then will show that field as blank. Then when you click the update, it clears out what you previously had. To get around that, you should use:

```
<input name="test" value="<?php echo htmspecialchars($content,ENT_QUOTES) ?>" />
```

which then gives you this output in the field:

```
"What are you talking about?" she asked, "that is ridiculous!"
```

but the html looks like this:

```
<input name="test" value="&quot;What are you talking about?&quot; she asked, &quot;that is rediculous!&quot;" />
```

This is just a stab in the dark based on your description and based on personal experience. You will have to show your html or some of the php values for a more clear picture.

Comment: thanks for your answer, actually I didn't got your idea, would you please illustrate it on my code?. thanks

Comment: Well, I am just guessing, to be honest, based on what you have described. when you say it'd deleted, you mean the contents of a column is deleted?